# В чем разница между лазить или лазать?

Tags: выбор-слова

На Викисловаре это две раздельные статьи

- https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C
- https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C

но они сильно пересекаются, и этимология одна.
Есть ли в действительности разница и рекомендации к правильному употреблению?

Answer (score 1):

Both лазить (лажу) and лазать (лазаю) have the same meanings; the difference is in register. According to gramota.ru, лазить is neutral stylistically and can be used both in written and colloquial speech, whereas лазать is labeled in some dictionaries as colloquial; you can use it in oral speech, but it's frowned upon in writing.